# When a prop is changing const is backing to its initial values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this component which is a filter for a table..

handleSearch function is responsible to update const filters... its work perfectly when dataIndex props is the same, but when it changes, filters value is backing to it's initial value, an empty array.

I can't manage to resolve it, I've already console log everything.

```
import React, { useState, } from "react";
import { SearchOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Select,  Button, Space } from "antd";

const TableFilter = (props) => {
  const {
    filterType,
    filterMode,
    filterOptions,
    FilterSelectOnFocus,
    dataIndex,
    setSelectedKeys,
    selectedKeys,
    confirm,
    clearFilters,
  } = props;

  const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]);
 

  const SelectFilter = (
    <Select
      style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: "block" }}
      type={filterType}
      mode={filterMode}
      name={dataIndex}
      value={selectedKeys}
      optionFilterProp="children"
      placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
      onFocus={FilterSelectOnFocus}
      showSearch
      onChange={(value) => setSelectedKeys(value ? value : [])}
      getPopupContainer={(trigger) => trigger}
      notFoundContent
    >
      {filterOptions?.map((type, key) => (
        <Select.Option value={type.value} key={key}>
          {type.label}
        </Select.Option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );

  const defaultFilterTypes = [
    {
      type: "select",
      element: SelectFilter,
    },
  ];

  const handleFilterType = () => {
    const type = defaultFilterTypes.find((types) => types.type === filterType);
    return type.element;
  };

  const handleSearch = () => {    
    
  
    console.log(filters) //is empty when dataIndex value change, when it's is the same it get the update value of the 75 line
    confirm();

    const newFilterValues = [...filters]
    
   
    const index = newFilterValues.findIndex(newValue => newValue.searchedColumn === dataIndex)
    

    if(index === -1){
      newFilterValues.push({ searchText: selectedKeys, searchedColumn: dataIndex})
    }
    else{
      newFilterValues[index] = {searchText: selectedKeys, searchedColumn: dataIndex}
    }

    setFilters(newFilterValues)
    
   
     
  }

  const handleReset = () => {
   
   console.log('reset');
    clearFilters();
    setFilters({ searchText: "" });
    setSelectedKeys([]);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
      {handleFilterType()}
      <Space>
        <Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={() => handleSearch()}
          icon={<SearchOutlined />}
          size="small"
          style={{ width: 90 }}
        >
          Search
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={() => handleReset()}
          size="small"
          style={{ width: 90 }}
        >
          Reset
        </Button>
      </Space>
    </div>
  );
};
export default TableFilter;
```

Table Component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Table } from "antd";
import { getTransactions } from "../../../../api/Transactions";
import { formatCnpjCpf, formatCurrency } from "../../../../utils/masks";
import TableFilter from "../../../../shared-components/ant-design/containers/TableFilters";
import { getPartnersAsOptions } from "../../../../api/Partners";

const Insider = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [paginationValues, setPaginationValues] = useState({
    current: 1,
    pageSize: 50,
    total: 0,
    position: ["topRight"],
  });

  const [partners, setPartners] = useState([{value: null, label: 'carregando...'}])

  const context = "insider";

  function getColumnSearchProps(
    dataIndex,
    filterType,
    filterMode,
    filterOptions,
    FilterSelectOnFocus
  ) {
    return {
      filterDropdown: ({
        setSelectedKeys,
        selectedKeys,
        confirm,
        clearFilters,
      }) => {
        return (
          <TableFilter
            dataIndex={dataIndex}
            filterType={filterType}
            filterMode={filterMode}
            filterOptions={filterOptions}
            FilterSelectOnFocus={FilterSelectOnFocus}
            setSelectedKeys={setSelectedKeys}
            selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
            confirm={confirm}
            clearFilters={clearFilters}
          />
        );
      },
    };
  }

  async function getPartners(){
      
     if(partners.length > 2){
       return
     }

     const response = await getPartnersAsOptions(paginationValues)
     setPartners(response.data)
     

  }

  const columns = [
    {
      dataIndex: ["transactionType", "desc"],
      title: "Tipo de Transação",
      sorter: true,
      key: "orderTransactionType",
      ...getColumnSearchProps("orderTransactionType"),
    },
    {
      dataIndex: "transactionDate",
      title: "Data Transação",
      key: "orderTransactionDate",
      sorter: true,
      ...getColumnSearchProps("orderTransactionDate"),
    },
    {
      title: "Nome origem",
      dataIndex: ["source", "name"],
      sorter: true,
      key: "orderSourceCustomerName",
    },
    {
      render: (render) => formatCnpjCpf(render.source.document.value),
      title: "Documento origem",
      key: "sourceCustomer",
      ...getColumnSearchProps("sourceCustomer", "select", "tags")
    },
    {
      title: "Nome destino",
      dataIndex: ["target", "name"],
      sorter: true,
      key: "orderTargetCustomerName",
    },
    {
      render: (render) => formatCnpjCpf(render.target.document.value),
      title: "Documento destino",
    },
    {
      render: (render) => formatCurrency(render.value),
      title: "Valor da transação",
      key: "orderValue",
      sorter: true,
      align: "right",
    },
    {
      render: (render) => formatCurrency(render.chargedTariff),
      title: "Tarifa",
      key: "orderChargedTariff",
      sorter: true,
      align: "right",
    },
    {
      render: (render) => formatCurrency(render.cost),
      title: "Custo",
      key: "orderCost",
      sorter: true,
      align: "right",
    },
    {
      render: (render) => formatCurrency(render.revenue),
      title: "Receita",
      key: "orderRevenue",
      sorter: true,
      align: "right",
    },
    {
      title: "Parceiro",
      name: "Parceiro",
      dataIndex: ["partner", "name"],
      key: "orderPartnerName",
      sorter: true,
      align: "center",
      ...getColumnSearchProps(
        "orderPartnerName",
        "select",
        "multiple",
        partners,
        getPartners)
    },
    {
      title: "id da transação",
      name: "id da transação",
      dataIndex: "id",
    },
  ];

  useEffect(function transactions() {
    async function fetchTransactions() {
      const response = await getTransactions(context, paginationValues);

      if (response) {
        const { data, pagination } = response;

        setData(data);
        setPaginationValues(pagination);
      }
    }
    fetchTransactions();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return <Table dataSource={data} columns={columns} />;
};

export default Insider;
```

Comment: Often when state is being set to its initial value it's because the component has been remounted. In which case, the issue is more likely to be in the component above. Maybe `dataIndex` is the key being used to render `TableFilter`, for instance - it would be useful to see it.

Comment: @lawrence-witt I going to update my awnser with the above component

Comment: sould be React.memo a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You could move this piece of code

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]);
```

In a higher level

Comment: I managed to solve the problem centralizing filters state using redux, solved the problem but has to be a better solution.